# How many listeners are too many observer pattern?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

My class were inheriting from two Listeners already. And I need to add one more listener. It became something like below:

```
class DatabaseManager : public DatabaseChangeListener, 
                        public PropertyChangeListener,
                        public RenumberListener
```

Should I avoid too many observers? Even though listeners are abstract classes it bothers me a bit that I am using multiple inheritance. I am curious has any one had experienced something like; because too many observers code became complex and buggy ?

Comment: Well, first of all I'd ask **why** you don't want to observe three objects. Is there any issue with that?

Comment: For example it bothers me a bit that I am using multiple inheritance. Also I am curious about people experiences. Even I haven't have any problems yet maybe someone else have bad experience.

Comment: Multiple inheritance isn't _bad_. It's a nice tool that may be abused (not in this case, IMO).

Comment: Multiple inheritance of pure virtual interfaces generally isn't bad.  Multiple inheritance from classes that aren't just interfaces is where the opinions will very more widely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The major signs of smell here are the fact that your class is called `DatabaseManager` (sounds like a god-object), and also the specialized tone that the interfaces have to them (e.g.`RenumberListener`).

There's nothing inherently wrong with supporting several event hooks, nor with multiple inheritance in and of itself. You might just need to group some interfaces into one clear one that describes what your class *does*, its basic right to exist, who uses it, and for what purpose.

Also note, implementing an interface is a type of functionality directed at the *consumers* of the class. If there's no need for generic interfaces, it's better not to have them, for otherwise you might find yourself with an interface per member function in the system at one extreme, and at the other, no clear guideline on what makes an interface and what doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reduce the number of classes, you can try to abstract away the different type of messages your listening to by creating a basic listener interface, e.g.,

```
virtual void onEvent(Subject * subject, Message * message) = 0;
```

Then you register your DatabaseManager for different type of events? This way you can still use single inheritance. I know that system like Qt etc use this for dispatching events.

But as far as I know, if your base classes (DatabaseChangeListener, PropertyChangeListener and RenumberListener) are pure abstract, you will not encounter problems with multiple inheritance.

Comment: Hmmmm and if they are not pure abstract classes? What may the problem be? Of course names may clash but there are workaround for that. Event pattern and observer pattern use a pretty different approach.

Comment: If they have member variable, you can have the following problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem

Comment: Member **variable**? However it's not an issue in this case (in general just something you should take care of, not an inherent reason to avoid multiple inheritance) because you're composing listeners: _passive_ methods called through each exposed interface, not from an hypothetical super-derived class. BTW the _problem_ arises if there is an ancestor method overridden in derived classes and called from most derived one...

Answer (score 0):

Don't use inheritance. Implement one listener interface and use onEvent method to handle it passing event to different handlers. Subscribe your object on different event types. This way you can easily change any events and handlers without changing your DatabaseManager. Even new events doesn't require much from DatabaseManager.

Consider using something like *Chain of Responsibility* to make your manager class fully undependable of event types. It could use just a chain of IHandler objects, which can be injected in constructor